# Which sql select runs faster

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have simple question which sql select runs faster? Here is the example.

I have 500 products and I want to select cheapest and most expensive I am trying to get it as fast as possible because there will be more products everytime so

1. TWO SELECTS

   ```
   SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1;
   SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1;
   ```
2. ONE SELECT

   ```
   SELECT min(price), max(price) FROM table;
   ```

second option looks faster but is limited by what i can get any types? ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Suggestion: Try running both and timing them yourself?

Comment: at this time it is impossible i have to work with real data and 500 products are not enough for good comparing but thx :D i tried it already

Comment: One Select will outperform Two.

Comment: Then why does it matter?

Comment: You're the only person that can "test" which is faster, without knowing all about your database and infrastructure, we can only guess..... bulk load your products to 500,000 and try it

Comment: When using two selects, in the both queries you select all the fields!

Comment: Set up a test db, populate it with data from your production environment. If you feel it is not enough load, insert some more via cross joining. Besides that, execution plans should not really differ due to the amount of data you have in your table.

Comment: download heidisql and activate profiler and see the time returned

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have an index on `price`, so it'll require a full table scan in both cases

Comment: Create an index on the `price` column, then I'd expect options 2. to be faster when only that column is queried (unlike as in your example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

~1.4 million records, hope this provides some rough metrics

First query:
1 row in set (1.23 sec)

Second query:
1 row in set (1.21 sec)

Third query: 
1 row in set (0.40 sec)

Comment: @user790454  I have a table similar to what the OP probably has, ran the 3 queries and supplied the OP the data

Comment: thanks a lot :D your example answered my inner question if it is even important with that specific amount of products even 10 000 more product would not make any big difference thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Answer of your question really depends on your database server, from the tags I guess you're using MySQL, but even versions can really make a difference. A great database server executes the query in the fastest possible way.

Furthermore, your database structure can influence your query performance, using the right attributes as keys can increase the performance of searches by tenfold. (You'll lose performance on inserts).

In this particular case you should try both these query and test which is faster. (I think PHPmyAdmin has this functionality).